# php escaping apostrophe in array issue

Tags: php, arrays, escaping

I have an issue with the below array, where the 1st one (should be Alpe d'Huez) is not escaping/being found.

Am I escaping the apostrophe wrong?

```
<?php

  $images = array (

  'Alpe D\'Huez' => 'images/flags/small/france_sm.jpg', 
  'Le Corbier' => 'images/flags/small/france_sm.jpg',   
  'Les Deux Alpes' => 'images/flags/small/france_sm.jpg'    
  );

  if (isset($images[$this->item->title])) {
?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not being found"? Can you show what data you are comparing it against?

Comment: where come `$this->item->title` from and who is that escaped?

Comment: What is the value of `$this->item->title`. Note that you use a capital `D` in your code and a lower case `d` in your text above.

Comment: Remember that you can use double quotes `"` to encapsulate the string if you need a literal single quote in it. Although there is nothing wrong with the above code - your should `var_dump($this->item->title);` and verify that it contains what you think it does. Keep in mind that not everything that looks like a single quote actually is one - for example, this `’` isn't one... Also remember that your code will be case sensitive and not forgiving of extra whitespace - the strings must be identical for your code to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's perfectly escaped like that.

Maybe the problem is with the value that you are comparing against. Try 'Alpe D\\'Huez' to see if in your value the apostrophe is double-escaped or try other apostrophe types like <kbd>`</kbd> or <kbd>´</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

As bardiir says, it's escaped just fine.  I note that your question says "Alpe d'Huez" (lower case d), but your array says "Alpe D'Huez" (upper case d).  It's case sensitive - could that be the issue?